# Trigger an action in a text field from a button

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking for advice on how to trigger this view function insertNewLine from a button (see view and template below). I'm guessing there's probably a better way to structure this code. Thanks for your help.

```
// view
App.SearchView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  insertNewline: function() {
    var value = this.get('value');

    if (value) {
      App.productsController.search(value);
    }
  }
});

// template
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view App.SearchView placeholder="search"}}
  <button id="search-button" class="btn primary">Search</button>
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the mixin `Ember.TargetActionSupport` on your TextField and execute `triggerAction()` when `insertNewline` is invoked. See http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/zc9AA/

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view App.SearchView placeholder="search" target="App.searchController" action="search"}}
    {{#view Ember.Button target="App.searchController" action="search" }}
        Search
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.searchController = Ember.Object.create({
    searchText: '',
    search: function(){
        console.log('search for %@'.fmt( this.get('searchText') ));
    }    
});

App.SearchView = Ember.TextField.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
    valueBinding: 'App.searchController.searchText',
    insertNewline: function() {
        this.triggerAction();
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm guessing the mixin on for App.searchController is not required, only on App.SearchView.