# Ember.js change router statement within view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Suppose I have a view:

```
Cellar.SearchTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    insertNewline: function(){
      // Cellar.SearchController.loadResults();
    }
});
```

And I have a route:

```
Cellar.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('search', { path: '/search'});
});
```

How can I change app url to `host/#/search?` when submitting the view's textfield?
Or what is the best and most logic way to implement search forms in ember applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this working using:

```
App.SearchField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    insertNewline: function() {        
        this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('search', this.get('value'));
    }
});
```

This will transition to search route, so you can load and filter the data on `model` hook.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Nekpy/) is a jsfiddle with the demo

Comment: Works, thank you. By the way, is there a better way to build forms with ember.js with passing parameters to url and without page reloading on submit?

Comment: Hmm that approach don't reload the page like a f5 in your navigator. And ever the content need to be replaced to show the data found, with dom manipulation or changing the template. So I think this isn't a problem. Other resource that I have found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682172/trigger-an-action-in-a-text-field-from-a-button, is a bit old. But, I still prefer my approach because, the url will match the search, by example: hitting foo in text field will become the url in http://youhost/#/search/foo. So you can share the link :)

Comment: But in this case I must implement search query as an object? But I preferred a `host/search?query=amenra` for example, so I could add some filters later

Comment: You can return a plain array, and in your template use the  `{{this}}` instead of property path, in the each helper. I have used the object just to have the information about the current text searched. About the query, ember doesn't have it out of the box, you need to use this plugin https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-query